# rails has many relations in includes where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

Let's say Company has_many Employee

I want to get all the Companies that it's Employees are all female.

But the following code will return all the companies which has at least one female.

```
Company.includes(:employees).where(employees: { gender: 'female'})
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyE Postgres

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres, you can do an `INNER JOIN` between companies and employees, then `GROUP BY company_id` then use a `HAVING`to

The SQL would look like:

```
SELECT companies.*
FROM companies
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.company_id = companies.id
GROUP BY companies.id
HAVING COUNTD(employees.gender) == 1 AND MAX(CASE employees.gender = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0) > 0
```

The having clause is a bit tricky. The `COUNTD(employees.gender) == 1` ensures that company employees are all of the same gender, the `MAX(CASE employees.gender = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0) > 0` ensures that the gender female (the MAX would evaluate to 0 if they were all male).

And the ActiveRecord equivalent would look like:

```
Companies.joins(:employees).group("companies.id").having("COUNTD(employees.gender) == 1 AND MAX(CASE employees.gender = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0) > 0")
```

Note that some of this is database-specific, so if you get any errors let me know.